# Vuetify theme doesn't change

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

As [doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/style/theme) said i used this to change default theme of my project:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
 theme: {
 primary: '#ff0000',
 secondary: '#ff0000',
 accent: '#ff0000',
 error: '#ff0000'
}
})
```

But nothing happens. Default primary color(#1976D2) is still there with no change. Why it is not working?

Comment: Some example code where it's not working?

Comment: <v-icon primary >add</v-icon>
add icon color will be default color of primary.(#1976D2)
 @Traxo

Comment: `primary` attribute is deprecated in newer versions. use `color` attribute instead:  `color="primary"`, ditto other colors

Comment: Both of them works fine... But color doesn't change.@Traxo

Comment: And what's your vuetify version?

Comment: "vuetify": "^0.16.9" @Traxo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing theme with `Vue.use` is not supported in older versions of Vuetify.
Upgrading Vuetify to 0.17.0 or higher will solve your problem.

Comment: source? afaics https://vuetifyjs.com/releases/0.16/#/style/theme says it can be changed in that way

Comment: Oh i meant editing theme with `Vue.use` is not supported in older versions. I fixed my post.

Comment: As Traxo says, the official doc for v0.16 actually mentions customization with Vue.use. But (at least in my case,) `Vue.use` did not 
create $vuetify.theme property when I use Vuetify 0.16...

Comment: I also suspected version at first, so I only checked docs without testing it myself. Lol, wonder why it mentions it if it didn't work. I checked on github, so you are indeed correct `Theme colors are now defined in the Vue.use statement instead of stylus`https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v0.17.0