# How to change theme light(default) in Vuetify 2.x in CDN mode?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

there is another similar topic  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709558/how-to-change-the-theme-colors-in-vuetify-in-standalone-cdn-mode/58013883#58013883) but i think that answer is not updated , if you see the codepen in that link is not working anymore , im trying to change the theme without having to add color atributte always on each component , i just want to define the theme color and continue coding the design , i did this trying to change on created method the theme color but is not working .

im using just cdns no vue-cli , no Vue.use like the other topic , i think the other topic was resolved but in vuetify 2.x that answer doesnt fit. thanks.

```js
//JAVASCRIPT

var vuetify = new Vuetify ({
  theme: {
      primary: '#9e9e9e',
      secondary: '#000000',
      accent: '#8c9eff',
      error: '#ff00ff'   
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify : vuetify,
  data: () => ({    
  }),
  methods: {
  },
  created(){     this.$vuetify.theme.primary = '#ff00ff';
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container grid-list-xl>
        <v-btn class='rounded'>Default</v-btn>
        <v-btn class='rounded'>Primary</v-btn>
        <v-btn class='rounded'>Secondary</v-btn>
        <v-btn class='rounded'>Accent</v-btn>
        <v-btn class='rounded'>Error</v-btn>
      </v-container>         
     </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true;` in your created method

If you want to customize the theme, you need to specify which theme (`themes.theme.dark`)

```js
//JAVASCRIPT
const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      dark: {
        primary: '#9e9e9e',
        secondary: '#000000',
        accent: '#8c9eff',
        error: '#ff00ff'
      },
    },
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify : vuetify,
  data: () => ({    
  }),
  created(){
    this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container grid-list-xl>
        <v-btn class='rounded'>Default</v-btn>
        <v-btn class='rounded primary'>Primary</v-btn>
        <v-btn class='rounded secondary'>Secondary</v-btn>
        <v-btn class='rounded accent'>Accent</v-btn>
        <v-btn class='rounded error'>Error</v-btn>
      </v-container>         
     </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: i have done that before but as you could see , the colors , primary , secondary and the others doesnt load. i try to add  --> this.$vuetify.theme.dark.primary = '#ff00ff'; but nothing , i cant customize the palette color by default . i dont want to add 'color="primary"' to each component . thanks for reply . do you know how to set the theme color by default (not light theme , my own custom palette color without add atributtes to new components)?

Comment: it works, your template used the same button type though. I updated my code to pass the type to button

Comment: maybe im not being clear , put primary on class atributte is different from what i want to do , i dont want to add atributtes or paste the class , because thats the same . i want to customize all the theme. not component by component .  something like create my own theme. or customize light theme or dark theme ,but just once time . not every time when i add some component to my html. , v-btn without atributtes is by defaut light i think . other components has diferent color borders because the theme has those colors. thats what i want , not customize v-btn , v-drawer .. v-etc ..

Comment: How do you expect `<v-btn class='rounded'>Default</v-btn>` and `<v-btn class='rounded'>Primary</v-btn>` to render differently if you don't provide some way of differentiating?

Comment: sorry , i think thats confusing , its my mistake . i dont want that . i just want to v-btn by default get the color that i specify as default in theme . the error color by default in some input could be green if i want but by default not setting that color as an atributte. there is some components that by default has colors from theme. im thinking like angular material  but maybe thats my mistake . i dont know if thats possible .

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood, the example code threw me off. I don't believe there is a way to do that without altering the css directly or compiling the css (not from cdn). You may be able to use a `default` or `primary` class to all the the elements, which, depending on the size of you project, may still be less work than dealing with css directly or compiling css.

Comment: thanks for your replies , i aprecciate it . well anyway . i think i ll left this ask because maybe there is no a way to solve this without make a little css file .